# Return array back through nested functions with Javascript

Tags: javascript, callback, nested

Good evening everyone. I know this will seem like an extremely easy subject for many here, but I've been struggling for a while to reconstruct a function I have in order to make it dynamic and reusable site-wide.

The main struggle I'm having is returning an Array using the following:

```
var arr = getData("admin/fullDatabaseAccess.php");
```

This doesn't return the array as expected. Now, without writing every possible variation of what I did to the **getData** function in an attempt to return the array which it creates, I'll first show you the original function which works:

```
function getData() {

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "admin/fullDatabaseAccess.php";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        processResponse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function processResponse(response) {


    var arr = JSON.parse(response);

    // do stuff with the array - I originally modified the DOM using jQuery here, however I now want to use this entire getData function as a more generically useful function

    }

}
```

I would then trigger the **getData** function on the single page which I was using this code with to generate an array, followed by modifying the page elements with the array data.

**THIS BRINGS ME TO MY PROBLEM** - I tried to make this function re-usable across the site by creating this version below, and calling the array data using the code line I posted at first *(var arr = ..)*:

```
function getData(file) {

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = file;

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        processResponse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function processResponse(response) {
    var arr = JSON.parse(response);


    return arr;


}
```

}

I cannot seem to feed the data back to the variable. I've tried restructuring the function quite a lot to **return** values within the nests etc but I've got to the point where I'm confusing myself and can't really show the examples I tried as I deleted them and decided to start again.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a callback to `getData`, like this

```
function getData(file, cb) {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = file;

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      // Calls the callback function with the response data
      cb(processResponse(xmlhttp.responseText));
    }
  }

  xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlhttp.send();

  function processResponse(response) {
    var arr = JSON.parse(response);
    return arr;

  }
}

getData(file, function(data) {
  // data is now what's being returned from processResponse()
});
```

Comment: I appreciate this! The call back specifically on processResponse() is the missing link that I never created!! Thank you for the help - everything is functioning perfectly.